Server 20016 FTP with user isolation
I have a Server 2016 with IIS FTP service running on it. Only users from a specific AD group are allowed to access it. In addition to that, user isolation has been configured to use the AD property for each users. All of this works perfectly fine, until it doesn't.
For some reason, that I cannot pin-point, after roughly a day users loose access with ftp error message User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible
I've tried various ftp settings to fix it, none of them helped. Even restarting the iis/ftp service does not fix it.
The only thing that fixes it is a restart of the whole server. Once I do it everything starts working perfectly fine again, until it doesn't again.
Any idea what is happening here? Did anyone experienced a similar issue in the past.
